# What is the equivalent of CellValueChanged event in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, datagridview, datagrid

I am modifying existing WPF code.  The code , the xaml file,  uses a DataGrid as opposed to DataGridView.

I need to use CellValueChanged event instead of CellEditEnding.  Thanks.

```
<UserControl x:Class="myclass.view"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
         <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <!--<RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Row="0" >
        <Border Background="Transparent">

            <Border.ContextMenu> 
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Name" Command="{Binding Path=CreateNewNameCommand}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete Name" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteNameCommand}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Border.ContextMenu>                                               
            <DataGrid
  Name="dataGrid1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFolderPlane.FolderPlaneItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGridItem}" 
    vw:DataGridDoubleClick.DoubleClickCommand="{Binding FolderPlaneItemDoubleClickCommand}"
     CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BorderBrush="White"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToHeader" Header="" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding MyIcon, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" Header=" Name" IsReadOnly="False" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToHeader" Binding="{Binding LatestMod, Mode=OneTime}" Header=" Version" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToHeader" Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=OneTime}" Header="  LatestMod" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanShowCatContextMenu}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Condition1ContextMenu}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanShowWFContextMenu}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Condition1ContextMenu}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>-->

    </DataGrid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you put the "event handler" in the setter for the presumably bound property? A little bit of XAML/code could help.

Comment: Do you want this code to run when ANY value changes, or just a specific one?

Comment: Also, could you just switch to DataGridView if you need that specific event? It sounds like you are able to modify pretty much anything you want.

Comment: @LordTakkera I am still a novice and I don't know how easy it is to change the whole infrastructure to DataGridView. But as the first option, the answer to your first question is I want this code to run  when the value of the first Column is changed by the user and I want the changes to be committed as well.

Comment: They are pretty similar, but it sounds like you just need to modify your bindings (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this does what you intend (I'm still not totally sure, your first column is an icon, why would that change?)

First, change your Mode to either TwoWay or OneWayToSource. This allows changes in the cell to automatically update the underlying model (this may "commit" the changes unless you are bound to a database). The difference between the two is that with TwoWay, the view will change if the underlying model is modified, OneWayToSource will not.

Second, set the UpdateSourceTrigger to "PropertyChanged", which will cause the source to be updated every time the value changes (instead of requiring it to lose focus).

```
"{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Finally, put the code you want run (this could also do your "commit" step) in the setter of the bound property (or have it call a function that does so).

```
public String MyProperty
{
   get { return _backField; }
   set
   {
      _backField = value;
      BuisnessLogicAndCommit();
   }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Comment: Thank . Questions and comments for you  ;  1- trying to get rid of the icon in the first column, as I said this is existing code and I am trying to get my head around it.

Comment: 2- What is a line of code to set the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged? I am not able to do it in XAML for some reason, I guess my syntax is wrong.                                           3-Setter of the bound property? I would appreciate specific code if possible.  Thanks

Comment: I tried to adress (2) by providing the binding string, and (3) by providing a sample property that the binding from (2) references. I'm not sure how to help with (1), can you not just delete the column if you don't want it?

Comment: I implemented all your suggestions but things are not working yet.  The remainder of the code is much more complicated and for example now it says Name is read only and cannot be TwoWay.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have to continue the work on this tomorrow. If I fix my other problems and then if your solution works I will definitely mark it as an answer and if I have more question regarding what you suggested I will post here. If you can, please check back in 20 hours. Thanks again.

Comment: Were you able to get your code working? I am available if you still need help.

Comment: No,the code's a big mess I am afraid. It starts with a window with two panes in it. The left pane is a NavTreeView and the right pane is Border with a DataGrid on it. The left pane is a list of Directories and SubDirs. The right pane displays the list of anything under the leftside directory which means it can be a directory or a file, the right pane has three columns Name,Version, Date. So my problem is that when I rename something in the Right pane then I can not sort based  column and it gives the exception of "Sorting Not Allowed During Edit/AddItem" MVVM and WPF are used.Very confusing.

Comment: The reason I posted this question is I was thinking to use DataGridView instead of DataGrid and maybe things would be easier but right now I am just thinking about how to break this up and debug it.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a different problem. I'm sorry the codebase you are working on is such a mess. Is it at least trying to update the backing field/property on value changed like your question originally asked?