# WPF Data Grid Cell Changed Get previous value and current value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, event-handling

I'm trying to update the grid if there's a change made in the cell.

Seems simple, how is this done?

Here's my code:

```
private void report_datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool update = false;
        if (e.RemovedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            if (e.AddedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                var res = (Researcher)((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem;
            }
        }
        e = null;
        if (update)
            UpdateGrid();
    }
```

I thought removed cell and added cell had the old value and the new value but it doesn't. It's actually showing different rows. I need to compare the old values, run a stored procedure and then update the grid basically. Everything is being held up by the fact I can't get the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedCellsChanged only gets fired when the **selection** changes, not when data in the cells changes, and thus will not help you make your comparison. The added/deleted cells are those that were selected and deselected, with no regard to value changes.

The "correct" way to accomplish this (and really probably the easiest) is to bind your rows to objects (and the cells to properties), and then perform your stored proc in the setter, which does have access to the old values.. See my answer to a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155883/1783619).

If you need an explanation of that answer or some sample code I would be happy to provide it, just let me know.